# ALAssetsLibrary permission message

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

I want to add custom permission message for ALAssetsLibrary permission message. 
Similar like CLLocationManager purpose.
I searched for this but did not found any solution.

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Info.plist file, add value for key `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` or `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html):

> NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription (String - iOS) describes the reason
>   that the app accesses the user’s photo library. When the system
>   prompts the user to allow access, this string is displayed as part of
>   the dialog box.
>
> iOS 6.0 and later